Vertical Scroll Bar Not Working in QTableView
I have a dialog with a QTableView in it. It is the size for three rows and when a fourth is added, a vertical scrollbar appears as expected. However, the scrollbar does not function to move the rows up or down. Clicking the up or down or using the slider does nothing.
If you highlight a row and use the cursor keys to change the selection, the scroll bar moves with the selected row as one would expect it to. Thus, the scrollbar works to show you where you are in the list, but does not work to move and change visibility in the list.
Is there a property, or combination of properties, that control this? I have tried changing a few things with no change is results.
